# Optional parameters in where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a C# form for searching in a table with different options that user can filter search procedure.

I have 4 textboxes for example txt1 , txt2 ,txt3 and txt4.

User can fill each of textboxes for searching like txt1 or txt1 and txt2 or txt1 and txt and txt4 or all of them and left the other empty and use all combination of thise textboxes. So how can I write one select procedure to cover all of this options.

I wrote this procedure but it wont help:

```
CREATE proc sp_searchZ
@minprice bigint=null,@maxprice bigint=null,@minarea int=null,@maxarea int=null,@location nvarchar(50)=null,@kind nvarchar(50)=null
as

SELECT *
  FROM Landtbl
 WHERE ((@minprice is null and @maxpriceis null) or ([Price] between @minprice and @maxprice))
 and
       ((@minarea is null and @maxarea is null) or ([area] between @minarea and @maxarea))

 and   ((@location is null)or([location]=@location))
 and   ((@kind is null) or ([kind]=@kind))
```

Comment: What do you mean "it wont help"? I think your basic logic is sound, are you getting zero records when expect some?

Comment: `@maxpriceis null` is that typo in your store procedure or only in this question?

Comment: sorry,I got it....but forget my code...what can I do when user dynamically filter and fill some of textboxes?

Comment: Before you go any further you need to read this article about catch all queries. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Two other comments. You should not use select * in your real code. The second is the prefix on you procedure name. I personally can't stand prefixes because they add nothing to the clarity and make it harder to find them in a list. The reason I am saying anything here is because your prefix is "sp_". This is reserved by MS for system procs. This means if you don't define the schema the engine will first look in the sys schema and if there is an update to sql server it might render your proc unusable.

Comment: @SeanLange I have more than one procedures and all of them start with sp_ and work correctly

Comment: Up to you but MS even says not to do that. There is a small performance hit as the engine will first examine the sys schema when you run your procs unless you explicitly name the schema everywhere in your code. They work today but if the next update there is a name collision, the engine will try to run the MS proc and your code will fail. Check it out for yourself. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+avoid+sp_&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to implement this is to use dynamic T-SQL. In your stored procedure, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @sqlString nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @sqlWhere nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @sqlParams nvarchar(max);

SET @sqlString = 'SELECT * FROM Landtbl '
SET @sqlWhere = 'WHERE 1=1 '

IF (@minprice IS NOT NULL and @maxprice IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlWhere = @sqlWhere + 'AND [Price] BETWEEN @minprice AND @maxprice '
END;

IF (@location IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlWhere = @sqlWhere + 'AND [location]=@location '
END;
-- any other conditional logic

SET @sqlParams = N'@minprice bigint,@maxprice bigint,@minarea int,@maxarea int,@location nvarchar(50),@kind nvarchar(50)';

SET @sqlString = @sqlString + @sqlWhere;

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlString, @sqlParams, @minprice ,@maxprice ,@minarea,@maxarea,@location,@kind
```

This should work nicely and can be used to do some really complicated things. I hope this helps

Comment: tnx but i dont know what EXEC sp_executesql mean.i have to write it end of procedure?what does exactly do this code?

Comment: EXEC sp_executesql will run the command you create dynamically. It is built in SQL so you dont have to do anything. You can still call your stored procedure as normal. Have you tried it yet? Put all my code in a storedProc definition, declare the appropriate parameters and run it

Comment: can i remove this last line from my procedure?if yes.how i edit this procedure?

Comment: I use linq 2 sql and when i wanna add this procedure to my programm It says :unknown return type  and the return types for following stored procedures could not be detected.then ask me set it by my selef.so what can i do with this message?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for dynamic SQL here, I do this sort of thing ALL the time, like this (remember I said your logic is sound?):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((@optionalparam IS NULL) OR ([field]=@optionalparam))
```

You've already done that, so, if you are not seeing results as expected, comment out all of the where clause and add each bit back in one at a time and you'll soon catch the bit that isn't working.

EDIT:

Try this, open SSMS and open a new Query window and enter the following:

```
DECLARE @minprice INT /* or whatever datatype you are using */
DELCARE @maxprice INT
SELECT @minprice=1, @maxprice=9999

SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  Landtbl
WHERE 
     ((@minprice IS NULL and @maxprice IS NULL) OR ([Price] BETWEEN @minprice AND @maxprice))
```

if that works then add the next bit

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  Landtbl
WHERE 
     ((@minprice IS NULL and @maxprice IS NULL) OR ([Price] BETWEEN @minprice AND @maxprice))
 AND ((@minarea is null and @maxarea is null) or ([area] between @minarea and @maxarea))
```

if it works add the next bit and so on until it fails. The bit you added last is the bit not working.

Comment: Actually dynamic sql is a reasonable approach here but not required as of sql 2008. It was about the only way to do this several years ago and keep the performance acceptable. The pattern you are using is my preferred approach too but you need to make sure you add the OPTION RECOMPILE so you don't get stale execution plans that are inefficient with differing parameters.

Comment: @Sean, yeah totally agree with all you say, but I didn't want to over complicate at this point as the OP seems to have a bit trouble getting the actual query to work.

Comment: I cant get it.can you explain more plz

Comment: @arshiadivsalar ok, but you need to tell me exactly what your problem is

Comment: @DaveBecker another problem of my application is when i want to convert what i get from textbox to int64(because of bigint variables in stored procedure),i faced with 'Cannot convert from System.DateTime' to 'string' error....I think it happens because of some empty textbox

Comment: @arshiadivsalar is that a different problem? post another question if it is. I'm spending valuable time here, I want to help, but one thing a time. get the SQL working first, check my edits.

Comment: @DaveBecker the code work when procedure has one part when i add the other condition to first code,It work but need to user use both option together...for example if user wanna fill just one textbox and left the other emty the select querry return nothing from table and i have to fill both textbox

Comment: it could be that the column you are checking (e.g. [area]) is null in the data. try this ...(ISNULL([area], 0) BETWEEN ... AND ...)

Comment: @DaveBecker i dont have any null column in my table